# Compute $T^{65}(f_1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2 over \mathbb{R}.$ Let $\alpha = \{f_1,f_2\}$ with $f_1=(1,0)$ and $f_2=(1,1)$

$a)$ Consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$T((x,y))=(-x+2y,-x+y)$$

Find the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the ordered basis $\alpha$ (on both instances of $\mathbb{R}^2$

My solution for $a)$:

$T(1,0)=(-1,-1)=0f_1-f_2$

$T(1,1)=(1,0)=f_1+0f_2$

Which gives the matrix representation$$[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha}= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

$b)$ Compute $T^{65}(f_1)$

Not sure how to complete this question, possibly choose a clever basis which gives a diagonal basis to make it easier to find $L_{A^{65}}$ which will need to be used within the equation $T^n=\phi_\beta^{-1} \circ L_{A^n} \circ \phi_\beta$

Not sure if i'm on the right path or not, if I am not sure what basis to choose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or you could find that $$[T] = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\pi/2) & \sin(\pi/2) \\ -\sin(\pi/2) & \cos(\pi/2)\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $T^2=-I$, hence $T^{64}=(-I)^{32}=I$, thus $ T^{65}=T$.